# Compile error in C++ using Linux program make

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to port over this section of code from C to C++. Its basically replacing the snprintf statement into a C++ implementation.

```
   if (len > 0)                        // If statement for 0 length buf error
    {
        localTime(tv, &etime2);

        // Printing to the supplied buffer in the main program
        char timebuf[80];               // Buffer to hold the time stamp
        oststream oss(timebuf, sizeof(timebuf));

        oss << etime2.et_year << ends;
        cout << timebuf << endl;
//      snprintf(buf, len, "%02i %s %02i %02i:%02i:%02i:%03i",
//      etime2.et_year, month[etime2.et_mon], etime2.et_day, etime2.et_hour,
//      etime2.et_min, etime2.et_sec, etime2.et_usec);
```

I've commented out the original `snprintf` just so I have it for reference. I need to print that exact string using `cout`, OSS and `oststream`. I've included the proper headers `iostream`, `strsteam`, and "using namespace std;". However when I run it using "make" I get the following errors

```
g++ -g -Wno-deprecated -c fmttime.cc fmttime.o
fmttime.cc:14:22: error: strsteam.h: No such file or directory
fmttime.cc:15:21: error: iosteam.h: No such file or directory
fmttime.cc: In function 'char* formatTime(timeval*, char*, size_t)':
fmttime.cc:273: error: 'oststream' was not declared in this scope
fmttime.cc:273: error: expected ';' before 'oss'
fmttime.cc:275: error: 'oss' was not declared in this scope
fmttime.cc:275: error: 'ends' was not declared in this scope
fmttime.cc:276: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
fmttime.cc:276: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [fmttime.o] Error 1
```

Here is my make document for reference.

```
#Variables
PROGRAM = plot
OBJS = plot.o fmttime.o
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wno-deprecated
LIBS = -lm -lcurses

#Rules
all : ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM} : ${OBJS}
        g++ ${OBJS} ${LIBS} -o ${PROGRAM}

%.o : %.cc
        g++ ${CXXFLAGS} -c $< $@

clean:
        rm ${OBJS} ${PROGRAM}
```

So I've been trying everything, I included the .h's after the headers, but I know in C++ its not necessary. I don't understand why its telling me `iostream` and `strstream` are out of scope...

Comment: Can you show your include directives?

Comment: It's `<iostream>` and `<sstream>`, not `<iosteam>` and `<strsteam>` -- they're streams not kettles ;-)

Comment: `<iosteam>`, sick `<3`.

Comment: Haha sorry dumb mistake on my part. But the strstream was actually given to me in lecture :S

Comment: is there no such thing as strstream? because using sstream is giving me errors....

Comment: This has nothing to do with `make`, which you could easily determine by running `g++ -c fmttime.cc` directly.

Comment: @PresidentRFresh `strstream` is [also deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream).  Best to post a new question specific to those errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are using deprecated (and misspelled) headers.

Use `<sstream>` and `<iostream>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have typo:

```
oststream //^^typo
```

You need to include correct header files:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sstream> //not strstream, deprecated
```

with correct namespace std:

```
std::cout;
std::endl;
```

or using namespace std;